# How can I add a div box on my Spotify mini player controls section that fades out on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spotify

Is it possible to add a solid white div rectangle that covers the control section of the Spotify mini player but fades out whenever I roll my cursor over the album 300px x 80px mini player?

I would also like to note that:

1. I'd want the control buttons to be clickable whenever the box fades out completely.
2. Whenever I remove my cursor from the player, I want the white box to reappear.
3. The playlist will be situated absolutely in the bottom left corner of my webpage. My theory is that I can just add a floating div box that'll cover the control section and fade when hovered over. Similar to a random div box on a webpage that fades out on hover, but the box will be positioned precisely to line up with the control section. Something to do with absolute positioning?

[Such as how the control section is revealed then recovered in this gif.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCOjX.gif)

The code:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:121937535:playlist:3MVhXBisjj553mJQoq1eqd&theme=white" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: i assume the player is hosted by spotify or some other service or else you would have shown the code. if that's the case, no, it's not possible.

Comment: To get a more specific answer to your question, we'll need to see the relevant code.  HTML segment for the area in question on the mini player, and the jQuery you've attempted.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/mglee/pen/PbOVzN

You can do something like this
It creates a nice effect, you could even put your email or some other text inside the box

Also, if you use `div.class img:hover`

You can achieve a similar effect with an image.

If this doesn't help reply and I can assist you